# Phing and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, pear, phing

I'm using Jenkins on Windows 7 and I would like to use phing with it. I installed the corresponding plugin but in the build I've this error :

```
[src] $ cmd.exe /C '"phing.bat -buildfile "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\Test\utils\build\build.xml" ci -logger phing.listener.DefaultLogger && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
'phing.bat' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex‚cutable ou un fichier de commandes.
Build step 'Invoke Phing targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

In English, `phing.bat` is not recognized as internal or external command...

For the phing plugin configuration, I put :
Targets : ci
Phing Build File : utils/build/build.xml
And "Use ModuleRoot as working directory" is checked (by default)

With Wamp, I installed pear and phing. In the environment path, I've default variables for pear (PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR, PHP_PEAR_DATA_DIR...).

The command line `phing --help` works and I also tried to directly put the command line in Jenkins `phing -f $WORKSPACE/utils/build/build.xml build -Dws=$WORKSPACE` but nothing happened after a build (folders described in builld.xml weren't created).

Answer (score 1):

Ha! Just solved this.

- Like the other guy said, make phing available on your path.  You can test in the command line.
- Then, the step I always - always! - forget: **restart the service**.

Maybe I'll get a tattoo on the back of my hand or something. Restart the dad-blasted service.

Answer (score 0):

The directory in which phing.bat is located needs to be in your `$PATH` variable. Otherwise you need to specify the full path to `phing.bat`.